# Копирование файла по Uri из Intent . Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, contentprovider

Пробую осуществить копирование файла из внешней памяти телефона в Internal storage
Запускаю Activity c **Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)**
Выбираю файл для копирования. При попытке копирования

`kotlin.io.NoSuchFileException: /document/C2D6-5EC6:Documents/скриншот.jpg: The source file doesn't exist.`

Если я правильно понял: Проблема не в функции копирования, а неподходящем пути к файлу-источнику (*/document/C2D6-5EC6:Documents/скриншот.jpg*), который пришел в intent

Как правильно осуществить копирование? Использовать 
`getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(myuri)` ?

Или есть какой-то более интересный вариант?

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 24

(Kotlin)

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import com.lfom.modbuster.R
import java.io.File


class ConfigFileFinder : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = this.javaClass.simpleName

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_config_file_finder)
    }

    private val FIND_FILE: Int = 0xA


    public fun onFindFile(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "*/*"
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, FIND_FILE)
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == FIND_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.w(TAG, data?.data?.path )
            val inpFile = File(data?.data?.path ?: return)

            if (!inpFile.canRead()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Can't read file ${inpFile.absolutePath}")
            }
            try {
                val newFile = inpFile.copyTo(File(filesDir.path, inpFile.name), false)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
```

**UPD**

Пока я остановился на таком варианте (код на kotlin):

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == FIND_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Empty Intent for file copy")
                return
            }

            try {

                val inpFileStream = baseContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data)
                val outFileStream = openFileOutput("default.prj", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

                inpFileStream.use { input ->
                    outFileStream.use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я лично сегодня 3 часа на это потратил. Кроме `getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(myuri)` ничего не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема кода в том, что вы пытаетесь копирать `File`, а надо копировать контент `Uri`

По большому счету, кроме `openInputStream()` ничего другого работать не будет, поскольку `Uri` может указывать на все что угодно: на внешний диск, SD карту, сетевое устройство или вообще на адрес в сети, на облаке ну и т.д., соответственно никак не гарантируется возможность конвертации `Uri` в `File`

В данном частном случае, когда `Uri` содержит `Document` можно попробовать так:

```
DocumentFile documentFile=DocumentFile.fromSingleri(context, uri);
if(documentFile.isFile()) {
    File file=new File(URI.create(documentFile.getUri().toString());
}
```

Но даже это не гарантирует срабатывание. `DocumentFile` может быть виртуальным файлом указывающим на BLOB в SQLite